# Terminating app due to uncaught > exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, objective-c

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward - but alas, I'm getting a crash. I'm simply trying to set my UILabel with the text returned from the *users_name* field:

**.m**

```
NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
[DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


   self.userData = [responseObject mutableCopy];

   self.username.text = [self.userData objectForKey:@"users_name"];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    });


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

**The console data returns:**

```
2016-04-05 12:25:36.877 [1331:350069] This is the Other User Data (
        {
        address = "Vancouver";
        userbio = "There is currently no bio available for this user. If you have added your bio, and require assistance, please contact the  Team.";
        "users_name" = Brittany;
    },
```

**That said, this line is causing the crash:**

```
self.username.text = [self.userData objectForKey:@"users_name"];
```

**And this is the error:**

> 2016-04-05 12:25:36.878 [1331:350069] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15a23c100 2016-04-05
>   12:25:36.881 [1331:350069] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15a23c100'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x181d51900 0x1813bff80 0x181d5861c 0x181d555b8 0x181c5968c 0x1000cce9c 0x1000c72bc 0x1000d3cc4
>   0x100459bf0 0x100459bb0 0x10045f658 0x181d08bb0 0x181d06a18
>   0x181c35680 0x183144088 0x186aacd90 0x1000d4c88 0x1817d68b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

How might I fix this? It seems like it should be simple...

Comment: can u try userData[@"users_name"] ? and is userData is NSDictionary ? IF it fails, try to log userData[@"users_name"].

Comment: It looks like it thinks userData is an Array (the reason is `-[NSCFArray objectForKey:]`) I'd try placing a breakpoint and verify that `userData` is actually a dictionary and not an Array

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes, doing it that way fails. Same crash error.

Comment: also try to use valueForKey instead of objectForKey

Comment: @BillL I've defined userData as a dictionary in my header file... @ property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *userData;

Comment: Since responseData is of type id the compiler won't stop you from assigning it to userData, so if it comes back as an NSArray at runtime it will cause a crash if you use NSDictionary methods on it, but won't be caught at compile time.

Comment: Bill is right. You have an array of dictionaries. try to use userData[0][@"users_name"]

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No, do not use valueForKey.

Comment: why @rmaddy ? IS it to avoid some crashes ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Only use valueForKey when you have a clear and specific need to use key-value coding. To get a value from a dictionary you use objectForKey.

Comment: where and how do you log " This is the Other User Data "? @Brittany

Comment: ok, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks-maddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `userData` is an Array type. Array have no key values.
Try: 
 `[[self.userData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"users_name"];`

Comment: I get the error: "No visible @interace for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector objectAtIndex when I type this in.

Comment: I suspect that is because you declared userData as an NSDictionary up top. Change the type to NSArray, then I suspect this will work.